# Geo Intent Label not showing in Google Maps App

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-markers

Since my Google Maps app updated recently, now **version 10.11.1**, the following code does not show the label as expected, [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#location_search), and previously working:

```
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:38.8951,100.0364?q=38.8951,100.0364(foo)")).setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
  if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) == null) {
    intent.setPackage(null)
  }
  startActivity(intent)
```

And neither does this version (with `0,0` immediately after `geo:`):

```
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=38.8951,100.0364(foo)")).setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
  if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) == null) {
    intent.setPackage(null)
  }
  startActivity(intent)
```

Neither does the example code in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#location_search) show a label:

```
// Display a label at the location of Google's Sydney office
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=-33.8666,151.1957(Google+Sydney)");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

[image: no "Google Sydney" label on Moto G5]

Comment: Confirmed - works on 10.10.1, doesn't work on 10.12.1.

Comment: @xinaiz Thanks for the confirmation. Unfortunately I could not find any meaningful way to report this bug to Google. Their Maps team passed the buck to the app team, and there is no conventional bug reporting system for the app where multiple people can vote.  If you know any way to inform Google, please let me know.

Comment: I just encountered it myself, and noticed the older Maps app in my emulator is showing the labels but the latest version in my phone as of today ignores the label completely.

Comment: Today the label is working fine for the latest version of Google Map,but when i was trying to check it again immediately the label is disappearing.

Comment: @JimaleAbdi the label works fine if you are offline; but stops working when you are online

Comment: @user2297550 if you get any solution please let me to know

Comment: @JimaleAbdi there is no solution. Only Google can fix the problem. I hope you have added your feedback to the issue filed with google in the accepted answer below.

Comment: @user2297550 yes of course i was added, we are waiting till google fix it

Comment: Lol, they still didn't fix if after all that time. Great company!

Comment: June 2020 problem still exists.

Comment: @ispiro sheer hubris of google -- forget fixing, they haven't even acknowledged the issue. not even a single comment from them on the bug tracker.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Update:** Scheduled to be fixed in v11.12 perhaps before the end of January 2022.

No solution still even with latest map update 10.12.1 the label still does not show even if the documentation still says it should
I've created an issue on Google's Issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129726279

hopefully we'll have some information shortly.

Comment: Everybody visiting this question, please add a comment to the bug report, and star it too.

Comment: Can anyone update the status as i am working on 10.18.2 version which is latest one . Still the issue is there. Any alternate solution ? Please let me know.

Comment: Still no solution :(

Answer (score 1):

[Per Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129726279#comment175), it's a bug in the Google Maps app. It's fixed in version 11.12.

Answer (score -1):

I think we are going about it the wrong way here. If I was Google, I would also feel insecure about allowing developers to post directions with an abstract destination label, I am sure they never plan to fix this.

I recommend the following solution according to Google's new standards. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE`

If you look at most apps these days, including the ones I have built, this allows us to post a LAT/LONG for the user to go to with Google's own Address values built in as the destination label.

To actually launch the Google Maps application, simply launch a web intent, I use the application context in this case.

```
    fun startGoogleMaps(context: Context, lat: Double, long: Double) {
        startWebBrowser(
            context,
            Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=$lat,$long")
        )
    }

    fun startWebBrowser(context: Context, link: Uri?) {
        if (link != null) {
            val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, link).apply {
                addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
            if (webIntent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
                context.startActivity(webIntent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user2297550 I understand the frustration.This is not only a helpful work-around the current issue, but also how many of companies and projects have chosen to go about building it. It simply starts the directions with actual text queried by Google themselves instead of the ugly Lat/Long alternative. I have given an explanation into why Google may be putting this issue on freeze, as not to "suckup" to them, but to give a possible insight to the issue.

Comment: Where did my comment disappear?

Comment: Its a regression however. It used to work fine for years. I first started using this feature in 2015. It failed sometime in early 2019 and hasn't been fixed.